# Find the real parameter so as the equation has no real solutions....

Tags: parametric, quadratics

My question is:

For which values of parameter $a\in \mathbb{R}$ the following equation
$$25^x+(a-4) \,5^x-2a^2+a+3=0$$
has no real solutions?

---

My idea is:

First of all we should transform the equation above in a quadratic equation but noting $5^x=t$ where $t\gt0$. So first of all I think that a quadratic equation has no real solutions when $D\lt 0$, but the second case , I think is when $D\gt0$, but the solutions are negative. But although it seems like logical, I still do not get the right, convenient solutions. 
I hope you help me solve this problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For real solution the discriminant of $$(5^x)^2+5^x(a-4)+3+a-2a^2=0$$ must be $\ge0$

i.e., $$(a-4)^2-4\cdot1\cdot(3+a-2a^2)=9a^2-12a+4=(3a-2)^2$$ needs to be $$\ge0$$ which holds true for all real $a$

So, we have $$5^x=\frac{-(a-4)\pm(3a-2)}2$$

Now for real $\displaystyle x, 5^x>0$

Comment: I understand, then if I want no real solutions then I need the discriminant to less than $0$. But when I do this I get that $9a^2-12a+4<0$ has no solutions. So what can I do in this case?

Comment: @JohnG., There will be no complex root for real $a$

Comment: Yes, but I need such values of $a$ that the equation has no real solutions.!?

Comment: @JohnG., We are helpless:)

Comment: So what's the answer, "impossible to determine" or what?

Comment: @JohnG., Phrase is yours. One option :"There will be no complex root for real a"

Comment: As the OP states, you also have to worry that $5^t>0$

Comment: @Michael, Thanks for your great observation

Comment: @JohnG., Please find the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
25^x+(a-4) \,5^x-2a^2+a+3&=5^{2x}+(a-4) \,5^x-2a^2+a+3\\
&=(5^x)^2+(a-4) \,5^x-2a^2+a+3
\end{align}
Let $y=5^x$, then
\begin{align}
(5^x)^2+(a-4) \,5^x-2a^2+a+3=y^2+(a-4) \,y+3+a-2a^2=0
\end{align}
The quadratic equation has no real roots iff its discriminant less than zero. Hence
\begin{align}
D&=0\\
(a-4)^2-4\cdot1\cdot(3+a-2a^2)&=0\\
a^2-8a+16+8a^2-4a-12&=0\\
9a^2-12a+4&=0\\
(3a-2)^2&=0\\
a&=\frac{2}{3}
\end{align}
In this case, its discriminant will be negative if $a<\cfrac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Is it possible for $(3a-2)^2$, to be negative? I do not think so.

Comment: @JohnG. How about that? The problem is $9a^2-12a+4$ has only a single root. You can draw the number line to prove it where $D<0$.

Comment: @JohnG. is right. The last line of this question is false.

Comment: @BenMillwood OK fine. I just tried to help though. At least don't down vote my answer. (T.T ) ( T.T)

Comment: @V-Moy: I appreciate the effort you make! Downvoting is not my way of insulting you or telling you you are terrible, you just made a mistake and I want other people not to be misled by it.

Comment: OK fine. You've ruined my day. I just feel bad when someone votes down my answer. Thanks anyway for being honest to me. I'm  going to  bed now. Nightly night @BenMillwood.

Comment: @V-Moy: aw :( I don't want to ruin anyone's day, but you gotta be able to admit when you make mistakes, we all do it.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer got as far as
\[5^x=\frac{-(a-4)\pm(3a-2)}2\]
observed that $5^x$ must be positive, but didn't comment on what this implied about $a$.

Well, let's take the $\pm$ to be $+$. Then
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{-(a-4) + (3a-2)}2 > 0 \\
\implies&2a+2>0\\
\implies&a>-1,\end{aligned}

whereas, if that $\pm$ is $-$, then:

\begin{aligned}
&\frac{-(a-4) - (3a-2)}2 > 0 \\
\implies&-4a+6>0\\
\implies&a<\textstyle\frac{2}{3}.\end{aligned}

Only one of these conditions need to be satisfied for a solution to exist, so there is always a solution for every value of $a$ (but, unusually for a quadratic, there is usually only one).